# UnmarshalException: Unable to create an instance

Tags: java, xml, jaxb, marshalling, unmarshalling

i have to work with several `xsd` files.
I generate the `JAXB` classes from the `xsd` files. I get the following result:

```
@XmlAccessorType(XmlAccessType.FIELD)
@XmlRootElement(name = "xmeldit.datenlieferung.1100")
public class XmelditDatenlieferung1100  extends TypeNachrichtG2G

@XmlAccessorType(XmlAccessType.FIELD)
@XmlType(name = "type.Nachrichtenkopf.G2G")
class TypeNachrichtG2G extends NachrichtG2G {
}

@XmlSeeAlso({NachrichtG2GRueckweisung.class,TypeNachrichtG2G.class})
abstract class NachrichtG2G {
    @XmlElement(required = true)
    protected NachrichtenkopfG2G nachrichtenkopf;
}

@XmlAccessorType(XmlAccessType.FIELD)
@XmlType(name = "Nachrichtenkopf.G2G", propOrder = {"identifikationNachricht", "leser", "autor"})
@XmlSeeAlso({ TypeNachrichtenkopfG2G.class, NachrichtenkopfG2GXInneres.class
})
public abstract class NachrichtenkopfG2G {
}

@XmlAccessorType(XmlAccessType.FIELD)
@XmlType(name = "type.Nachrichtenkopf.G2G")
public class TypeNachrichtenkopfG2G extends NachrichtenkopfG2G{
}

@XmlAccessorType(XmlAccessType.FIELD)
@XmlType(name = "Nachrichtenkopf.G2G.XInneres")
public class NachrichtenkopfG2GXInneres extends NachrichtenkopfG2G {
}
```

Now i want to `unmarshal` a Class `XmelditDatenlieferung1100`  Object. But i get a `UnmarshalException`. `Jaxb` wants to create an instance of `NachrichtenkopfG2G`. `NachrichtenkopfG2G` is abstract.
How can i say that `jaxb` use `TypeNachrichtenkopfG2G` instead of `NachrichtenkopfG2G` ?

I unmarshal the objects with:

```
JAXBContext jaxbContext = JAXBContext.newInstance("packagename");
XmelditDatenlieferung1100 unmarshal = XmelditDatenlieferung1100) jaxbContext.createUnmarshaller().unmarshal(filePath.toFile());
```

I have no idea. :-(

Comment: What's the code you use to start unmarshalling?

Comment: i add the code how i start the unmarshalling.

Answer (score 0):

I ran into exactly the same problem. This can simply be fixed by removing the `abstract` attribute in `xinneres-basisnachricht.xsd`.

So just change this:

```
<xs:complexType name="Nachrichtenkopf.G2G" abstract="true">
```

to:

```
<xs:complexType name="Nachrichtenkopf.G2G">
```

Comment: Yes that was the solution that i use but is this the common way to solve the problem? I dont think so.